# Context-aware username (e.g., git username instead of login name) in time-stamp

Tags: magit

I am a total emacs/elisp newbie and I can't figure out how to do this.

- I have `time-stamp-active t` with a pretty standard format: `time-stamp-format "Last modified %Y-%02m-%02d %02H:%02M:%02S MyUser")`.
- I have different git repos where I use other nicknames.

How can I write a function which checks if the file-in-buffer belongs to a git repository, if yes, substitute 'MyUser' with the local git user name, and if not revert to the default?

I googled around and I did not find anything useful to me...

Answer (score 1):

You can configure *per-repo* options following this magit [manual page](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Per_002dRepository-Configuration.html), but what you want is just git.

Then if you want to get your configured `user.name` or `user.email` from your elisp code, this should work:

```lisp
(shell-command-to-string "git config user.name")
```

Note that you're launching a short-living process for each call to obtain a parameter that probably you can call once and keep.